# Changing screen display" on click event" in the same page in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki-pages

i want to create web design in MS sharepoint online . By referring to the attachmenet below ,What i want to do is when i "click" this image "1click"(in yellow field)[image]

Then it show the data below.

But then when i click let say image"TMO". it change the below element into something else as shown below. [image]
I believe i need to use coding to do this maybe javascript, html, and css in this Wiki-page web part editor. My intention is to change the picture in "red circle" below into something else, but the "blue circle" remain when i click "process flow" image.[[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyNOE.png)[[image]

Can u help me with the code or any other easy way for me to do because im quite new to this coding stuff. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to use `iframe`, something like below

```
<p>Click on link bellow to change iframe content:</p>
<a href="http://www.bing.com" target="search_iframe">Bing</a> -
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org" target="search_iframe">Wikipedia</a> -
<a href="http://google.com" target="search_iframe">Google</a> (not allowed in inframe)

<iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org" width="100%" height="100%" name="search_iframe"></iframe>
```

Here between anchor tag `<a></a>` you will need to add image tag for your images

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730159/changing-iframe-src-with-javascript